# sed rounding a number to 2 decimals

Tags: regex, sed, decimal, rounding

I have a number i.e. 123.456789 and my question is how to round this to two decimals after dot, so it look like 123.46 using sed? Any ideas?
Alternatively, how to cut the rest after 2 decimals so in the end it would look like this: 123.45?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

Actually sed is not the rght tool for this, your should better use awk. Create an awk script like this:

```
echo 123.45567 | awk '{printf("%.2f\n", $1)}'
```

OR using BASH printf:

```
printf "%.2f\n" 123.45567
```

#### OUTPUT:

123.46

Answer (score 6):

Truncating it can be done with something like:

```
pax> echo hello 123.4567 goodbye | sed 's/\(\.[0-9][0-9]\)[0-9]*/\1/g'

hello 123.45 goodbye
```

This basically works by finding a string of the form `.dd[ddd...]` (where `d` is a digit) and replacing the whole thing with just the `.dd` (the parentheses act to to capture the `.dd` bit).

*Rounding* it is a little more difficult since it's not simple text substitution (you have to *change* the final digit to add one, if the next digit is five or more). You may need to resort to slightly more adaptable tools for that.

*One* way to do this (though I'm pretty certain it's not the *best* way) is with `Perl`:

```
pax> echo hello 123.4567 9876.54321 goodbye | perl -ne '
    @x = split;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $#x; $i++) {
        if ($x[$i] =~ /^[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$/) {
            $x[$i] = int ($x[$i] * 100 + .5) / 100;
        };
        print "$x[$i] ";
    };
    print "\n";'

hello 123.46 9876.54 goodbye
```

This does the rounding operation on every field that matches the desired pattern but, as stated, it's pretty ugly - I'm sure there are better ways (brian d foy, where are you?)

Comment: I'm certainly not hanging out in any sed bars. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since no one's managed to do rounding with `sed` yet anyway, here's a Python example for you:

```
$ echo "echo hello 123.4567 goodbye" | python -c "import sys, re
for l in sys.stdin:
    print re.sub(r'\d*\.\d{3,}', lambda x: str(round(float(x.group()), 2)), l)"
echo hello 123.46 goodbye
```

You can change 2 to something else to change the rounding accuracy.